# Function to create a string from a ChrW code

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, frameworks

In VB6 I could say

```
Dim s as string
s = ChrW(937)
```

But I did not find a function in .NET without using the Microsoft.VisualBasic runtime to do that.

Can somebody tell me how this can be done?

Is the following code correct?

```
Public Function ChrW(ByVal uKeyCode As Integer) As String

    Dim nChar As Char = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(uKeyCode)
    Return New String(nChar, 1)

End Function
```

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the C# equivalent of ChrW(e.KeyCode)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060576/what-is-the-c-sharp-equivalent-of-chrwe-keycode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var myKeyChr = char.ConvertFromUtf32((int) e.KeyCode)
```

as already mentioned in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060576/what-is-the-c-sharp-equivalent-of-chrwe-keycode).